# Upgrade matplotlib used within QGIS

Tags: qgis, python

I'm using the Python Console within QGIS 2.14.3 (MacOS). When I import matplotlib, it imports version 1.4.3 from '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-override/matplotlib/**init**.pyc'. I would like to update matplotlib to a newer version. How do I go about doing that so that QGIS will see it?

A related question: I have miniconda installed in a different location with matplotlib version 2.1.1. When I start python from a MacOS command line, import matplotlib imports from '.../miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/**init**.pyc'. Can I point QGIS to my miniconda install or would that be a bad idea?

I am trying to better understand how QGIS and python play together.

Answer (score 1):

As already been mentioned many times in GS exchange, the Kyng Chaos QGIS version uses the standard Apple Python version 2.x (and not others Python implementation, Homebrew, Anaconda, etc.)

The [Kyng Chaos installer of the Python module Matplotlib](http://www.kyngchaos.com/files/software/python/matplotlib-1.4.3-1.dmg) installs it into the `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-override` folder with a `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-override.pth` [pth files](http://bob.ippoli.to/archives/2005/02/06/using-pth-files-for-python-development/) that points to the precedent folder (same for his numpy, `numpy-override.pth` and scipy, `scipy-override.pth` installers)

[image]

As  these name implies, these override all other matplotlib,numpy or scipy folders installations.

You absolutely need the KyngChaos matplotlib installation to install QGIS: It checks to see if the folder exists in the Distribution file of Install QGIS.pkg)

[image]

```
if(!(system.files.fileExistsAtPath('/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-override/matplotlib/__init__.py') == true)) {
    my.result.title = 'matplotlib';
    my.result.message = 'QGIS requires the Matplotlib python module (kyngchaos build).';
    my.result.type = 'Fatal';
    return false;
```

When Qgis is installed, nothing prevents you from installing new versions of the modules with pip (`sudo -H pip install matplotlib)`.

You need to delete or rename the `matplotlib-override.pth` file or replace the content of the matplotlib-override folder with the new matplotlib folder.

But be careful because some libraries located in the QGIS application (`/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python`, `/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/grass/etc/python`) needs a specific version of the modules (especially numpy).