# Selectively install frameworks for macos QGIS?

Tags: qgis, python, mac, numpy, matplotlib

The [KyngChaos method](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis) is the one-stop shop for Mac users to install QGIS. This page has links to the critical frameworks and python modules, which he graciously packages and maintains himself. Have people have had success ***selectively*** installing some of those components but not others? Or replacing them with updates? Which packages are mission critical, and which ones can be replaced or updated?

I have had installed the KyngChaos versions of numpy (v. 1.9.2), scipy (0.16.0), and matplotlib (v. 1.4.3). I have uninstalled these versions of numpy and scipy, removed the `.pth` overrides in order to update via `sudo pip install -U`, and have had no adverse effects (yet). But QGIS does not like it if you do the same with matplotlib.

Comment: see [Upgrade matplotlib used within QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/266189/upgrade-matplotlib-used-within-qgis/266227#266227)

Comment: @gene 's link helps address the question. is there any more definitive experience on updating different modules?

Comment: Yes because I updated all the modules (numpy, scipy) because I work mostly with Python alone

Comment: You can also use  [Virtual Environments](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/)